# how continuously run function on page request

Tags: django, django-views

I want to use third party's REST API providing real-time foreign exchange rates  in my django app  which should continuously show changing exchange rates.

my code works but only on every page reload. but I want my code to be running continuously and showing exchange rate on page even if the page is not reloaded.

```
    def example(request)
        RATE__API_URL = 'REST API url'
        while True
            rate = requests.get(RATE__API_URL).json()
            b = rate['rates']['EURUSD']['rate']
            context = {'b': b}
            return render(request, 'example.html', context)
```

on my example.html

```
<h1>
    {{b}}
</h1>
```

code is running and does not show any errors

Comment: You could create your view that returns JSON with the new data and add custom JavaScript to your template that calls and updates your HTML in regular intervals.

Comment: Or you could use something more robust like https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: That while loop in your view will not work due to the nature of HTTP requests and Djangos views

Comment: I also thought about adding JavaScript but unfortunately I have zero knowledge of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can solve your requirement and none of them are the "right way", also much of it depends of what you have in your code, so I'll try to lay them out for you, and  given the extent of what needs to be done while providing some links so you can work on it, but I will not give code because you'll require a fair amount of tailored code (sorry for that) and the references are good enough for you to develop your own solution.

The first thing you have to keep in mind is than you'll need to solve two really big and really different requirements:

The first part of your solution is retrieving the data from the source in a timely manner. The second part is to have a way to update the data in the template without the need for the user to reload the page.

To retrieve the data you said you already have an API where you'll get the data, but your code is not an efficient way to approach this, and it also may generate a risk because it is prone to hit too many times the API server; the best way I can think of would be if the API has webhooks or push notifications to which you can subscribe (which I doubt), the second best choice is to implement a [Celery task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), that way you will be calling the data regularly, and you'll not eat the API service resources.

With the first part out of the way, what you have left to do is to implement a way to call regularly from the UI for the newest data. Perhaps the simplest way to solve it is to implement an asynchronous call with Javascript/JQuery embedded in a script inside your template, but remember:

1. For this to work you'll need a model to store the data (If you don't
   have an use for historic data, then just keep [the most recent
   one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/)).
2. You'll need a view that exposes the data to your UI call (one that sends a JSON)

Another solution is to implement websockets, and the best way to achieve this for Django is using [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You'll have to implement two main things:

1. In the backed you need to define the consumers flow so you can send
   the data to the UI.
2. In the template you need to implement the websocket connection and a way to handle the updating part of the data for the user.
3. If you choose this way, and given than you don't need historic data, you can obviate the model and go straight from the Celery task to the UI through the consumer.